# How to format time and check "working hours" in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've been playing with NSDate() but I hit a bump and need help. I need to check working hours and if user is using an app during open hours some green dot will appear.

I work with firebase and data for working hours is:

```
main 
---> key
     ----> working hours
           -------------->
                            Mon: 12:00-18:00
                            Tue: 11:30-21:00
                            etc.
```

I get the logic. Grab day in week. Grab correct line in Firebase. Grab user current time and see if it is given range. I'm still beginner but I would love to learn how to do this.

Can somebody direct me a little bit?
Here is only code I have for now:

```
// Check current time
        let userTime = NSDate()
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let now = formatter.stringFromDate(userTime)
        print(now)
```

Comment: You will need to be able to parse the working hours into a format that you can work with. If they are always in that format you can try using a regular expression to get the day, the open time, and the close time. Then you can check the current day, and see if the current time is between the open and the close time for that day.

Comment: Is your firebase set up so that you query for a day and receive the times back as a string?

Comment: @WillM. yes I have firebase like in example in my post.

Comment: well you can split that on the '-'. since you are using 24hr time, you can just strip the colons and convert them into 2 numbers (1200 and 1800), then do the same for the current time's HH:mm and then see if it is between them. Gets more complicated if days have multiple sets of open hours though.

Comment: they have... Okay, what can I do if there are multiple sets?

Comment: you could split them into each set and then for each set check if its inside the set. I would recommend making a struct for a set of open/close times, with a method that returns whether the current time is inside that set. Then, for each set struct for that day, check that method, and if any return true, then it is currently open.

Comment: okay, silly question... I have a hard time understanding basic. How do I create NSDate from a string (after I formatted it)

Comment: NSDateFormatter dateFromString

Answer (score 0):

Since no question should go unanswered ;)

Since your pattern is stable you can use Regular Expressions with named groups. Keep the regex pattern outside the function.

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<day>\\w{3}):\\s(?<openHour>\\d{2}):(?<openMin>\\d{2})-(?<closeHour>\\d{2}):(?<closeMin>\\d{2})",
                                     options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Here is a function that takes your input "Mon: 12:00-18:00", you can select the right now based on the correct day, or move the day checking into the function too.

```
func isOfficeOpenNow(input: String) -> Bool {

    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf8.count)

    guard let match = regex.firstMatch(in: input, options: [], range: range) else {
        assert(false, "Epic Fail!")
    }

    guard let dayRange = Range(match.range(withName: "day"), in: input),
        let openHourRange = Range(match.range(withName: "openHour"), in: input),
        let openMinRange = Range(match.range(withName: "openMin"), in: input),
        let closeHourRange = Range(match.range(withName: "closeHour"), in: input),
        let closeMinRange = Range(match.range(withName: "closeMin"), in: input) else {
        assert(false, "Did not find the named groups")
    }

    let day = String(input[dayRange])
    guard let openHour = Int(input[openHourRange]),
            let openMin = Int(input[openMinRange]),
            let closeHour = Int(input[closeHourRange]),
            let closeMin = Int(input[closeMinRange]) else {
        assert(false, "Failed to convert to ints")
    }

    print("day: \(day) Opens at: \(openHour):\(openMin) and closes at \(closeHour):\(closeMin)")

    // Lets check if its now open (not checking the day....sorry)
    let tz = NSTimeZone.default
    let now = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(in: tz, from: Date())

    guard let hour = now.hour,
        let minute = now.minute else  {
            assert(false, "this should never happen")
    }

    let rightNowInMinutes = hour * 60 + minute
    let opensAt = openHour * 60 + openMin
    let closesAt = closeHour * 60 + closeMin

    assert(opensAt < closesAt, "Opening after closing does not make sense")

    return rightNowInMinutes > opensAt &&
        rightNowInMinutes < closesAt
}
```

Here is how you could use it

```
if isOfficeOpenNow(input: "Mon: 12:00-18:00") {
    print("Store open")
} else {
    print("Store closed")
}
```